# can't use returned value in node.js

Tags: node.js, function, variables, callback

This function returns duration:

```
getEventLog.getId(uuid, function(err, id){
    if(err) return console.log(err)
    getEventLog.getDuration(id, function(err, duration, callback){
        if(err) return console.log(err)

    })
  });
```

If I add `console.log(duration)` below `if(err) return callback(duration)` I can see its value.

I'd like to use this as a variable in other functions. I tried just setting the entire function as a value like this:

```
var duration = getEventLog.getId(uuid, function(err, id){
    if(err) return console.log(err)
        getEventLog.getDuration(id, function(err, duration, callback){
            if(err) console.log(err)
            control.log(duration)
        })
    });
```

It didn't work though. I then thought a callback might be way but can't get one working. This was my attempt:

```
getEventLog.getId(uuid, function(err, id, callback){
     if(err) return console.log(err)
        getEventLog.getDuration(id, function(err, duration, callback){
            if(err) console.log(err)
            callback(duration)
        })
    });
```

How do I change this so I can use the duration value?

**Additional info**

If I try the call back I have

```
getEventLog.getId(uuid, function(err, id, callback){
    if(err) return console.log(err)
    getEventLog.getDuration(id, function(err, duration){
        if(err)
        var dur = duration
        callback(dur)
    })
});

var myVal = getEventLog.getId(function(dur) {
  console.log("myVal: " + dur)
});
```

I get:

> modules/getEventLog.js:36
>               callback(null, arrFound);
>               ^
>
> TypeError: callback is not a function

If I try the return I get:

```
  getEventLog.getId(uuid, function(err, id, callback){
    if(err) return console.log(err)
    getEventLog.getDuration(id, function(err, duration){
        if(err) return duration
    })
  });

var myVal = getEventLog.getId()
console.log("myVal: " + myVal)
```

I also get:

> modules/getEventLog.js:36
>               callback(null, arrFound);
>               ^
>
> TypeError: callback is not a function

I think it might get thrown when `return console.log(err)` is removed.

Apologies for the silly questions but I'm new to Node.js. Where am I going wrong?

I included getEventLog below for reference:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var readline = require('readline')
//var db = require('./dbPool');

//get file name
var options =  {
    "method" : "GET",
    "hostname" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : "18080",
    "path" : "/api/v1/applications/"
};

exports.getId = function (uuid, callback) {
    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {

        var chunks = [];

        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("end", function () {
            var body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks));

            var arrFound = Object.keys(body).filter(function(key) {
                if (body[key].name.indexOf(uuid) > -1) { 
                    return body[key].name;
                }
            }).reduce(function(obj, key){
                obj = body[key].id;
                return obj;
            }, {});
            callback(null, arrFound);
        });
    });
    req.end();
}

exports.getDuration = function (myId, callback) {
    //getEventLog.getId(function(err, id){

    //get file name
    var options =  {
        "method" : "GET",
        "hostname" : "127.0.0.1",
        "port" : "18080",
        "path" : "/api/v1/applications/" + myId
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        console.log(options)

        var chunks = [];

        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("end", function () {
            var body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks));

            var attempts = body.attempts

            var arrFound = Object.keys(body).filter(function(key) {

                return attempts[0].duration;

            }).reduce(function(obj, key){
                obj = body.attempts[0].duration;
                return obj;
            }, {});
            //console.log(arrFound);
            callback(null, arrFound);
        });
    });
    req.end();
 //   })
};
```

Comment: I don't see your function return anything? `console.log` returns nothing (`undefined`) and you don't even return from all execution paths.

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink what you want to achieve. You describe, that you want a return value, but you do not `return` anything. You execute a callback function (which is fine too).

A function can return a value like this:

```
function foo() {
    return 'bar';
}

var value = foo(); // value === 'bar'
```

Or you can execute a callback function (mostly async) and put your "return value" as a parameter into it, so:

```
function foo(callback) {
    // do some stuff here
    var duration = 123;
    callback(duration);
)

// executing foo, putting a callback function into it
foo(function(duration)) {
    // duration will be 123 here
});
```

---

**EDIT: Please note, that you should always only show the minimum of your code, which is needed to understand your problem.**
You actually thinking and coding correctly, but your function call is wrong (which I wasn't aware until your edit).

```
getEventLog.getId(uuid, function(err, id, callback){
    if(err) return console.log(err)
    getEventLog.getDuration(id, function(err, duration){
        if(err)
        var dur = duration
        callback(dur)
    })
});


/* 
 * take a look at this line: 
 * your function requires your first parameter to be an `uuid`, 
 * but you simply skipped it. Now your second parameter is null, 
 * resulting in "callback is not a function"-error.
 */
var myVal = getEventLog.getId(function(dur) {
  console.log("myVal: " + dur)
});
```

Just call your function correctly, by passing an `uuid` as first parameter and your `callback` function as the second.

Comment: thanks for the response. I added some information to my question in relation to your answer.